# Can a Python script run on a Debian machine and play a sound via ssh on my local machine?

Tags: python, audio, pygame

If so, which requirements are needed?

I've tried some libraries, like pygame, mpg123 but no succes, though.

Some errors:

**pygame**

```
pygame 1.9.6
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
ALSA lib confmisc.c:767:(parse_card) cannot find card '0'
ALSA lib conf.c:4528:(_snd_config_evaluate) function 
snd_func_card_driver returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:392:(snd_func_concat) error evaluating strings
ALSA lib conf.c:4528:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_concat 
returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1246:(snd_func_refer) error evaluating name
ALSA lib conf.c:4528:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer 
returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5007:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM default
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "som.py", line 3, in <module>
    pygame.mixer.init()
pygame.error: No available audio device
```

**mpg123**

```
High Performance MPEG 1.0/2.0/2.5 Audio Player for Layers 1, 2 and 3
    version 1.23.8; written and copyright by Michael Hipp and others
    free software (LGPL) without any warranty but with best wishes
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for 4294967295, skipping unlock
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for 4294967295, skipping unlock
ALSA lib confmisc.c:767:(parse_card) cannot find card '0'
ALSA lib conf.c:4528:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_card_driver returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:392:(snd_func_concat) error evaluating strings
ALSA lib conf.c:4528:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_concat returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1246:(snd_func_refer) error evaluating name
ALSA lib conf.c:4528:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5007:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM sysdefault
ALSA lib confmisc.c:767:(parse_card) cannot find card '0'
ALSA lib conf.c:4528:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_card_driver returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:392:(snd_func_concat) error evaluating strings
ALSA lib conf.c:4528:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_concat returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1246:(snd_func_refer) error evaluating name
ALSA lib conf.c:4528:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5007:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM sysdefault
```

Is it possible and I am just missing something, or it is not possible?
What am I missing?

PS: It's just a beep after a if validation, so I am aware that something happened.

Comment: If it is possible to play the sound with a shell command on the local machine then it is possible to play that sound from a remote machine running the same shell command through ssh client

Comment: trying to understand your question ... my guess is from your local machine you have ssh'd onto a remote box where you are running a process which you want to trigger a sound back on your local machine ?   keep in mind most remote servers do not have an audio card ( hardware ) hence your above server side audio card errors ...  of course your local box typically does have an audio card ... let us know

Comment: That's exactly what I want, but I am not sure if the machine has audio support or driver or hardware... I do have, locally. I believe, now, I should check for audio hardware or drivers there, then, to accomplish or to know if I am able to accomplish that. The pois is, there is not a real monitor there, still I can see the command line... I don't understand why I can't play audio and from the errors, and from your comments I guess there is none...

Comment: (Just gathering some thoughts) Likely you would need to create a virtual output device on the remote server and use some connection protocol to send data from that virtual device to your machine (most desirably through the same ssh connection, but it might be impossible through that channel). No clue whether such project already exists...